# Calling param object inside script block

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a folder remotely but the parameter that I type in command line doesn't pass in script block. Below code will only create directory webapp.

```
$computerName = "s3apdev0074"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -ScriptBlock { param([string]$appname) md d:\webapp\$appname}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$ComputerName = 's3apdev0074'
$AppName = Read-Host "Please enter the application name"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ArgumentList $AppName -ScriptBlock {
    Param (
        [String]$AppName
    )
    # DOS: 
    md d:\webapp\$AppName

    # PowerShell: New-Item -Path "d:\webapp\$AppName" -ItemType Directory
}
```

It seem you are only missing the `-ArgumentList` parameter to pass in your local variable.

More info here:

```
Get-Help Invoke-Command -Parameter ArgumentList
```

Comment: The code works but the value of $appname should be based on what I type in command line.For example  .\test.ps1 app1. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Answer updated, you only need to use `Read-Host` to accomplish this.